# Saving data to database using forms django

Tags: python, django, forms

Model

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()
```

Form

```
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    address = forms.CharField()
    city = forms.CharField()
    state_province = forms.CharField()
    country = forms.CharField()
    website = forms.URLField()
```

And view

```
def test(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print  form.cleaned_data
            p=Publisher()
            p.name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            p.address=form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            p.city=form.cleaned_data.get('city')
            p.state_province=form.cleaned_data.get('state_province')
            p.country=form.cleaned_data.get('country')
            p.website=form.cleaned_data.get('website')
            p.save()
            return HttpResponse("Done")
else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})
```

I am saving the data to the database when the submitted form is valid. 
But what I did is extracting each field from dictionary `form.cleaned_data` and then assigned it to instance of `Publisher` object manually for e.g `p.name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')`

My question is that is there is any way to assign the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary to `Publisher` object. In short can i do it like ,

```
p=Publisher()
p=form.cleaned_data
p.save()
```

Comment: Please look into modelforms here.. Your use fits the case of Model Forms perfectly..
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 1):

A perfect candidate for [`ModelForms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

```
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
```

and views:

```
def test(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            publisher = form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Done")
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ModelForms, it fits your case perfectly..

Full docs are available [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

But I will try and explain how to use your case with a ModelForm (although I'd suggest you go through the docs themselves and try it yourself)

Considering your existing model, create a forms.py file in which you need to create a ModelForm class as follows:

```
#Import your model here
from .models import Publisher
from django.forms import ModelForm

class PublisherForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
        fields = '_all_'
```

Note: You can use the 'fields' option to tell Django to restrict the fields it will be showing in the form. By default '*all*' is used to show and use all fields from your defined Publisher model.
After creating your ModelForm, you can populate it using a request.POST(or any other way)

```
f = PublisherForm(request.POST)
```

To save the data directly to the corresponding model, simply call the save() method. Remember, you are using a ModelForm, not a regular forms.Form, which means Django now knows which model to save to, so you can simply call .save() on your ModelForm instance.

```
f.save()
```

If you wish to perform cleanup operations on the populated form before saving, that can also be done. Check the docs for detailed explanations regarding that.